# using maven coordinate style episodes in wsimport

Tags: java, jaxb, catalog, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm building (multiple) complex `webservice` with base `XSD` types from all kinds of standards `(GML, SWE, XLINK, etc)`. Now, I would like to break up the compilation into more steps, preferrably one for each of the standards I'm using.

Advantages:

1) I can add create tooling libraries that I can re-use in all of my webservices on each of the standards.

2) I can make use of the power of `JAXB2 basics plugin`, which seems to work very nicely with the `maven-jaxb2-plugin (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2)` and create for instance interface bindings. This in contrast with the jaxws-maven-plugin plugin.

The final step would be using the `org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:maven-jaxb2-plugin` to create the actual web service that I can implement in an EJB (or call as a client).

Now, the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` plugin allows me to refer to episodes by means of their maven coordinate, as part of its  like this:

```
<episodes>
    <episode>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-test-episodes-a</artifactId>
    </episode>
</episodes>
```

How can I do this by means of the `org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:maven-jaxb2-plugin`? I've searched a lot, and experimented like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>example.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>                    
        <xjcArgs>
            <xjcArg>-b</xjcArg>
            <xjcArg>../cpt-xsd/target/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode</xjcArg>
        </xjcArgs>                  
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Which takes the episode file from the target dir of the (compiled) JAXB dependend project. This sometimes even fails in the maven build (why I did not figure out yet).

I've tried to use catalog files to make a mapping but (I think I saw somewhere a catalog mapping that took maven coordinates as destination), but haven't succeeded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of the [OGC Schemas and Tools Project](https://svn.java.net/svn/ogc~svn/ogc-schemas/trunk/)? (Disclaimer: I'm the author.)

Now, to your question. My guess would be that `org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:maven-jaxb2-plugin` does not support the "Maven coordinates" as you call them. This was a feature I've specifically implemented for my `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` (disclaimer: I'm the author).

From the other hand, episode file is nothing but a JAXB binding file. So you can simply extract this file from the JAR artifact (for instance using the `maven-dependency-plugin`) and then include it more or less like you do it already. Just don't point to directories in other modules, this is not reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware.. Found this a while ago. Thanks for that by the way! I do require some specific bindings (e.g. measuretype to bigdecimal) so I chose to make my own implementation (evolving from yours).

I came to a similar approach a while ago. I managed to breakdown each individual OGC project (and Xlink) into seperate modules, each containing: the XSD, catalog, an extCatalog (containing your mvn-coordinate-binding style), generated episode. So I can use those as dependencies (and develop specific tools for them).

Comment: I like the feature. So I would have liked to have it for the JAXWS plugin as well. (Perhaps they can steal from / delegate to your plugin. I issued an issue request on Jira, but never heard from it again.

Xlink has an interesting JAXB problemem by the way (when used in combination with episodal compilation). 

If you want, I can share my OGC projects with you

Comment: Or maybe I should implement the wsimport goal in `maven-jaxb2-plugin`. If your bindings generally make sense then I could overtake them to the main project. Please contact me valikov-at-gmx-dot-net.